# Deep search and replace for float values in javascript

Tags: javascript, parsing

I have a nested object and some properties has float values as a string. My objective is to convert those strings to number format.
Here is an example object

```
var myObj = {
  "value": "text",
  "params": {
    "check3": false,
    "check2obj": {
      "params": {
        "value3": 35,
        "value4": "0.05",
        "value5": "0.02",
        "value7": "hello",
        "local": {
          "value4": "263.03",
          "value3": 35,
          "value2": true,
          "value1": "hello1"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Once parsed, I want this object to look like

```
{
  "value": "text",
  "params": {
    "check3": false,
    "check2obj": {
      "params": {
        "value3": 35,
        "value4": 0.05,
        "value5": 0.02,
        "value7": "hello",
        "local": {
          "value4": 263.03,
          "value3": 35,
          "value2": true,
          "value1": "hello1"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried it with the below function but the string doesn't change to float

```
function parse(data){
    $.each(data, function(key, value){
        if(typeof(value)== 'object'){
            parse(value);
        }else{
            if(typeof(value) == 'string' && !isNaN(parseFloat(value))){
                value = parseFloat(value);
            }
        }
    });
    return data;
}

changedValues = parse(myObj);
```

Comment: this is easy and what have you tried?

Comment: Show us what you tried and what you have researched. Stackoverflow is not a free code writing service. The objective here is for people to help you fix **your code**

Comment: You are returning your input parameter. You need to apply the changes to it before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create recursive function to iterate trough nested object properties and then `parseFloat` method to transform value to float and `isNaN` method to check if its float or not.

```js
const data = {"value":"text","params":{"check3":false,"check2obj":{"params":{"value3":35,"value4":"0.05","value5":"0.02","value7":"hello","local":{"value4":"263.03","value3":35,"value2":true,"value1":"hello1"}}}}}

function parse(data) {
  for (let key in data) {
    const n = parseFloat(data[key])
    if (typeof data[key] == 'object') parse(data[key]);
    if (n && !isNaN(n)) data[key] = n;
  }
}

parse(data)
console.log(data)
```

Comment: You can just remove `n && ` but i wasn't sure what to do with 0